# How do I use completion by "Ctrl-n" with XVim?

Tags: xcode, vim, xvim

I use XVim, a nice product. I want to use code completion like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> on Vim, but it is not working in XVim.

So, how can I use completion like that with XVim?

Answer (score 2):

According to [its FeatureList](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/blob/master/Documents/Users/FeatureList.md), this isn't implemented (yet). Why don't you raise this on the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/xvim-developers), or [open an issue](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/issues)?!